# using ajax to get further mysql data using data already retrieved fro database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

I'm trying to build a product catalog where clients can select a product and be presented with product specifications and price. now the first thing i do is query all the products in the database omnicon_prod. from there i build an unordered list of items like such

```
$query = "SELECT  name, id, price, image, cost_per FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<li class="product" style="list-style:none;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px; width:150px;float:left;" id="'.$row['id'].'">
        <img class="productImage" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;width:150px;padding:10px;float:left;" src="'.$row['image'].'main-image.jpg">
        <div class="productText" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <div class="price" style="color:#fca204;font-weight:500;font-size:20px;font-family: "Conv_Geogtq-Th", sans-serif;">'.$row['price'].' <span style="color:#959595; font-size:14px; font-weight:100;">/'.$row['cost_per'].'</span>
            </div>
            <div class="name" style="color:#959595;font-weight:100;font-size:14px;font-family: "Conv_Geogtq-Th", sans-serif;">'.$row['name'].'
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>';
}
```

What i would like to do now is attach an anchor to each list item and should the client select an item that comes from the database they would be presented with further information such as the description etc. now i know this should be done with ajax but i'm not sure how as i am relatively new to it. I would like to trigger the ajax possibly by using the onClick even on an ancho tag. this is what i have tried thus far.

**the ajax**

```
function ajaxfunction(productID)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php-includes/products.php?productID=' + productID,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#productSpec").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**the products.php page**

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
 $query = "SELECT  name, price, image, cost_per FROM products WHERE `id` = ". mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["ProductID"]);
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //the content from the database that matches the id of the selected item
}
?>
```

please can someone help me with regards to where i'm going wrong and if it's wise to use an anchor tag to trigger this event. I basically adopted and tried to incorporate the dynamic multi-level select form option into one that uses a list to grab data...

Comment: where do you link the items in your unordered list to the JS function with the AJAX call? You could attach it to the <li> tag like this: $(".product").on('click',function(){ //put the ajax code here  });

Comment: okay cool thanks will definately try that. will let you know soon

Comment: so tried what you suggested. productid.php works correctly using the get function (only if i manually type in a url variable (e.g productid.php?id=4). it gets and displays information from the db correctly using the id supplied. still having a problem with ajax though. im not sure as to how to send the .$row['id'] of the clicked li item to productid.php to be used as a url variable. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ajax call you can check out these pages [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
Basically you add the data you want to send (object or string) as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ruben i managed to figure it out hehe. i'd like to share the final result. if there are any errors or security risks please advise me as to how i could improve the code...

**The Quote.php exerpt**

```
<?php
  include_once "php_includes/connect.php";
 $query = "SELECT  name, id, price, image, cost_per FROM products";
 $result = mysqli_query($db_connect,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<li class="product" style="list-style:none;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px; width:150px;float:left;" id="'.$row['id'].'">
        <img class="productImage" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;width:150px;padding:10px;float:left;" src="'.$row['image'].'main-image.jpg">
        <div class="productText" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
            <div class="price" style="color:#fca204;font-weight:500;font-size:20px;font-family: "Conv_Geogtq-Th", sans-serif;">'.$row['price'].' <span style="color:#959595; font-size:14px; font-weight:100;">/'.$row['cost_per'].'</span>
            </div>
            <div class="name" style="color:#959595;font-weight:100;font-size:14px;font-family: "Conv_Geogtq-Th", sans-serif;">'.$row['name'].'
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

**THE AJAX SCRIPT**

```
<script> 
$(".product").on('click',function(){ 
the_id = $(this).attr('id'); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php_includes/productspec.php?id=" + the_id,
        success: function(data){
          $("#productSpec").html(data);

            }
        });
});
</script>
```

**THE productspec.php PAGE**

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$productid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $_GET['id']);  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE `id` =  " . $productid;
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['id'].'</p>'; //just a test result i'd like to receive
     echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>'; //just a test result i'd like to receive
      echo '<p>'.$row['price'].'</p>'; //just a test result i'd like to receive
}
?>
```

thanks so much Ruben. I really appreciate the help you've given me and that you provided the tools to help me figure it out myself. I don't think i'll ever forget how to do this again hahaha. i'll mark your previous post as the answer!

Comment: There's a few things you could change to make the code a bit cleaner. first off in the ajax script I would put the url in a variable so you can pass that in as the url parameter. When you need more querystring parameters I will keep you code cleaner. second in the poductspec.php I would also use a variable for the output. This way you only need one echo statement. Glad to help. I always find it more useful to be pointed in the right direction, so I can find the solution myself. Helps me to remember the solution :-)

Comment: hehe man you're the best. your suggestion makes a lot of sense. will most definitely do a bit of cleanup. i'm not sure, however, what you mean by query string parameters. please elaborate? thanks

Comment: what I mean by query string parameters is the stuff you pass to you php page as data/parameters.. in the querystring for instance here you pass id as a parameter by going to productspec.php?id=12